# Angular ng-router not working

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, ng-view

I am learning angular-js and I am trying to use ng-route with ng-view.But somehow it is not working.

App runs on nginx.
My code is

src/index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>


        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/demo_controller.js"></script>



    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-view>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

src/js/controllers/demo_controller.js

```
demoApp.controller('demoController',function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

src/js/app.js

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

demoApp .config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/route', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/demo_template.html',
        controller: 'demoController'
      });
  }]);
```

src/templates/demo_template.html

```
<div  >

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"/><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>
```

nginx configuration

```
server_name mypr.app.local;

location /ui {
     alias /home/vagrant/www/mypr-ui/src;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
```

url I tried

```
mypr.app.local/ui/route
```

In the console I can see that  is getting commented out

```
<!-- ngView:  -->
```

Comment: HOW is it not work? What's the problem you are having?

Comment: I cant see the view on my page.And there is no error in console!

Comment: @HenryZou And ng-view is getting commented out !(Saw it in console )

Comment: your $routeProvider's 'route' points to "templates/page_1.html", but I only see "templates/demo_template.html" template.

Comment: Also, you can only have 1 "ng-app" per application. in your templates/demo_template.html, your have ng-app='demoApp'

Comment: Same I noticed, route is pointing to templateUrl: 'templates/page_1.html', and under template you have different file(src/templates/demo_template.html). Also add otherwise() also

Comment: @HenryZou Thanks for pointing out.Fixed these bugs but still not working.

Comment: need to use `#` in url. Default routing is based on hash. Read the router docs

Comment: @HenryZou It worked after adding otherwise() block.
Can you please post it as an answer!

Comment: Otherwise is not needed, you simply needed to point to the right address: http://localhost:8080/#/route

Comment: Yes, i will agree. But its good to have otherwise, so that if I type wrong URL it will inject default template

Comment: user3290349 : If my below answer works/clears your doubt you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="demoApp">
        <head>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <!-- Optional theme -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>
            <div ng-view>
            </div>


        </body>

    <script>
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

    demoApp .config(['$routeProvider',
      function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/route', {
            templateUrl: 'demo_template.html',
            controller: 'demoController'
          })

    $routeProvider.otherwise('/route');
      }]);

        demoApp.controller('demoController',function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Template:

```
<div>

    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"/><br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

    </div>
```

Change template URL according to your file location

URL like : http://localhost:8080/#/route

Answer (score 1):

Things, I've noticed:

1) Template file and path to it in router is incorrect. Change it to your template.

2) Your template file should not have directive ng-app.

3) You have to use url like:

yourapp/#/route